# index was out of range must be non negative and less than the size of the collection when generating script with data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to generate the script with data i am getting 
index was out of range must be non negative and less than the size of the collection in sql server when generating script with data. How can i resolve this issue.
[image: issue screen]

To get script with data i doing following steps

- right click on database.
- Task - Generate Script
- Select table .
- Select specified database object
- Select Table
- Select Advance The select type of database script to script data
- Press Next Then Next to start

Comment: i am trying to generate script with data for some table in database in SQL SERVER. Not using any code simply by SQL UI

Comment: Thank you for adding the steps you have carried out to cause the issue